# we can't use positional argument after the keyword argument. What's the reason behind it?

Tags: python, arguments, position, keyword

Here I have made a simple function that takes two parameters i.e firstname and lastname. I was trying different methods of passing the arguments. During this I encountered this problem. I was not able to use positional arguments after the keyword argument

```
def message(firstname, lastname):
    print(f'My first name is {firstname} and my last name is {lastname}')

#case 1: both are the positional args
message('Yanji', 'Lama')

#case 2: both are the keyword args
message(firstname='Yanji', lastname='Lama')

#case 3: first one is keyword args and second one is positional args
message('Yanji', lastname='Lama')

#case 4: second one is keyword args and first one is positional args
message(firstname='Yanji','Lama') #and I get the error here which says positional argument cannot appear after keyword argument
```

[image: Here is the image showing the error message]

I just want to know the depth reason behind it.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer to "why does this programming language work the way it does?" is usually "because whoever designed it, said so". In the case of Python you may actually find some reasoning if you dig deep enough in the mailing groups, but that's really part of the research you're supposed to do *before* asking the question on SO.

Comment: Can you clarify - are you asking about why do you have this issue or why Python (and any other language with functions accepting a mix of named and positional arguments) works this way?